# How to set the background color for colored items in the statusline to the background color of the statusline?

Tags: filetype, statusline, color

I am experimenting with creating a `statusline` and have opted for coloring different parts of it.

The problem is that while the item's foreground color is changed, the background is black and doensn't match the `statusline`, e.g.:

```
set statusline+=%([%1*%t%*]%)
```

How can I set the item's background color to match the `statusline` (or turn it "transparent")?

```
set filetype=vim
set laststatus=2
set showcmd
set showmode
set termguicolors

" %-0{minwid}.{maxwid}{item}

" :help gui-colors
hi User1 guifg=Green guibg=fg
hi User2 guifg=Purple guibg=fg
hi User3 guifg=Cyan guibg=fg
hi User4 guifg=Red guibg=fg
hi User5 guifg=Orange guibg=fg

set statusline=%([%f]%)
set statusline+=%(%m%r%w%h%)
set statusline+=%(%y%)

set statusline=
set statusline+=%([%1*%t%*]%)
set statusline+=%5*%(%m%r%w%h%)%*
set statusline+=%(%y[%{&expandtab?'S':'T'}]%)
set statusline+=%=%<%([%3*%l,%c%V%*]%)
set statusline+=%([%3*%P%*]%)
"set statusline+=%([%3*%l,%c%*]%)
set statusline+=%(%a%)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is answered directly under `:h 'statusline'`.

The syntax is simply `%*`. The actual highlight group will be one of *StatusLine*, *StatusLineNC*, *StatusLineTerm*, *StatusLineTermNC* just as expected.

UPD. Real highlight groups (not that "percent-star") are coloured *globally* by `:highlight` command. Even though `User1` is primarily intended for status line(s), it doesn't make it anything special. So you can link it to `StatusLine` or `StatusLineNC`, but not both at the same time. It really has nothing to do with status lines, just usual combo of `:execute`, `:highlight`, `synIDattr()`, `synIDtrans()` and `hlID()` left as an excercise.

Comment: I think the idea was to make `User1` the same background as whatever `StatusLine*` group is active (or at least one of them)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Updated. As it is, the question is not about status lines, but rather "how do I use :hi command?"